# C# Input string was not in the correct format

Tags: c#, parsing, text, text-files

I realize this is a very often repeated question, but I've read like 20 other ones and can't find an answer.

I'm trying to parse a text file and get an exception on the first line that the string is not in correct. The file resides in Unity's `TextAsset` hence the `file.text`. This return file contents as `string`.

`lines[0]` is read correctly to `15`, `Debug.Log()` in line 4 returns `2` so no extra characters remaining after split.

Code:

```
private void ReadFile()
{
    string[] lines = Regex.Split(file.text, "\n|\r|\r\n");
    Debug.Log(lines[0].Length);
    int width = int.Parse(lines[0]);
    int height = int.Parse(lines[1]);
    tab = new int[width, height];
    for (int i = 2; i < width+2; i++)
    {
        string[] values = Regex.Split(lines[i], "\t");
        for (int j = 0; j < height; j++)
        {
            tab[i, j] = int.Parse(values[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the file I'm trying to parse:

```
15
15
2   0   0   3   0   0   0   2   0   0   0   3   0   0   2
0   1   0   0   0   4   0   0   0   4   0   0   0   1   0
0   0   1   0   0   0   3   0   3   0   0   0   1   0   0
3   0   0   1   0   0   0   3   0   0   0   1   0   0   3
0   4   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
0   0   3   0   0   4   0   0   0   4   0   0   0   4   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   3   0   3   0   0   0   3   0   0
2   0   0   3   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   3   0   0   2
0   0   3   0   0   0   3   0   3   0   0   0   3   0   0
0   4   0   0   0   4   0   0   0   4   0   0   0   4   0
0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
3   0   0   1   0   0   0   3   0   0   0   1   0   0   3
0   0   1   0   0   0   3   0   3   0   0   0   1   0   0
0   1   0   0   0   4   0   0   0   4   0   0   0   1   0
2   0   0   0   0   0   0   2   0   0   0   0   0   0   2
#0  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14

# 1 - DW
# 2 - TW
# 3 - DL
# 4 - TL
```

And here's the same file with white space characters shown:

[image]

I don't know how to paste this, so this is just a screenshot from Word.

Comment: how are you reading the file?

Comment: try it with `int.Parse(lines[0].Trim())`

Comment: @Eser unfortunately, trim didn't work

Comment: @DanielA.White I'm  using Unity Text Asset which reads the file http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TextAsset.html

Comment: Note that you have an index out of array bounds issue in your loop.

Comment: @JamesR. Yeah I just got that seconds before I read your comment :) `[i-2, j]` is the corrent index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Regex to make sure non-digits are not included in your strings..

```
List<List<int>> lines = File.ReadLines(filename)
                        .Select(line => Regex.Matches(line, @"\d+")
                        .Cast<Match>()
                        .Select(m => int.Parse(m.Value)).ToList())
                        .ToList();
```

Comment: I'm getting an error that ReadLines is not defined. I got it to work ReadAllLine with a part of my code to split lines futher. I wanted to avoid using filename in string but I guess it'll have to do for now. Thanks